# AsyncTask isn't working with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am building song list application. I want to display splash screen while loading data. For that use I set an `AsyncTask` combined with ViewSwitcher to switch xml layout beetween splash screen (just logo and circle progressbar) and main screen. The problem is when it comes to puting data in ListView, I am using BaseAdapter which is in separate class, and it throws error `"The Constructor LazyAdapter(Home.LoadViewTask, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined"`.

This is source of Home Class which has AsyncTask:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mBtnNaslovnica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnNaslovnica);
    mBtnNaslovnica.setSelected(true);

    new LoadViewTask().execute();
}

//To use the AsyncTask, it must be subclassed
public class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{
    //A TextView object and a ProgressBar object
    private TextView tv_progress;
    private ProgressBar pb_progressBar;

    //Before running code in the separate thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        //Initialize the ViewSwitcher object
        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(Home.this);
        /* Initialize the loading screen with data from the 'loadingscreen.xml' layout xml file. 
         * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/
        viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(Home.this, R.layout.init, null));

        //Set ViewSwitcher instance as the current View.
        setContentView(viewSwitcher);
    }

    //The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {    

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    //After executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        /* Initialize the application's main interface from the 'main.xml' layout xml file. 
         * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/
        viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(Home.this, R.layout.main, null));
        //Switch the Views
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
    }
}

//Override the default back key behavior
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    //Emulate the progressDialog.setCancelable(false) behavior
    //If the first view is being shown
    if(viewSwitcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
    {
        //Do nothing
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Finishes the current Activity
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And this is the source of `LazyAdapter` class:

```
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(Home.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do any UI modification.. such as setting a label text, modifying list inside a AsyncTask.doInBackground.. because it is a separate thread...

```
  list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
```

you should put that part of the code before you call

new LoadViewTask().execute();

and inside the doInBackground()... as the last line.. 
put this line.. 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: can you get a list view shows up with all the songs.. without the loading bar??? does that part work for u? A simple activity with just listview inside it.. just load it with data using asyncTask.. and see if it shows up.. when thats down.. may be viewSwitcher is easy to do after...

Comment: i did that , and i doesnt work , its working only when i remove complete AsyncTask , but thats pointless

Comment: how does ur R.layout.main looks like??

Comment: i figure it out how to do that on other way :) but thnx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor in first parameter get Activity and you pass instance of LoadViewTask (this  referrs to the current instance of LoadViewTask),
instead of this use:

> adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, songsList);

Where **Home** should be name of your activity

Comment: it doenst working , well it removes error , but when i start application .. after splash screen it crashes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, for whatever reason, you're requiring an `Activity` as the first parameter of your constructor. By passing `this` to the constructor of your adapater you're passing an object of type `AsyncTask` which is not activity and doesn't have a context. So you should pass an `Activity` as the an argument in the overridden constructor for `LoadViewTask` and then use it as the correct argument for your constructor.
Nonetheless be careful when binding a context to an `AsyncTask` since it may lead to unexpected behaviours (the `Activity` may not exist anymore when `AsyncTask` tries to update it). `AsyncTask` is a very dangerous class to use since it has many synchronization-related flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be help,

```
onPostExecute include (Inside AsyncTask)

ExampleAdapter sectionedAdapter = new  EfficientAdapter(ClassInfoThread.this,getBaseContext());
listView.setAdapter(sectionedAdapter);
```

and in your adapter class add this constructor

```
public ExampleAdapter(ExampleThread exampleThread,Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub`enter code here`
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```